# initdb for postgresql on os x fails

Tags: macos, postgresql, macos-sierra

Having trouble installing postgres 10 on my Mac, version 10.12.5.

I've tried installing 2 ways:

```
(1) Downloading Postgres.app
(2) `brew install postgresql`
```

and tried to manually run a bunch of variations of these commands for `initdb`:

```
$ initdb /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/ver-10
$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

All yield the same error `FATAL: could not create semaphores: Invalid argument`.

Full trace:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "foo".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 10
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... 2018-03-12 20:49:58.654 PDT [98144] FATAL:  could not create semaphores: Invalid argument
2018-03-12 20:49:58.654 PDT [98144] DETAIL:  Failed system call was semget(1, 17, 03600).
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"
```

I'm not sure what `FATAL: could not create semaphores: Invalid argument` means. I've seen a lot of other answers related to insufficient space, but not this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I reinstalled Postgres.app, and then restarted my computer, and then opening the app and clicking 'initialize' fixed it. I still have no idea why though, and would love if someone could tell me what may have been causing the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the shared memory and the number of semaphores due to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/kernel-resources.html) page? I use `kern.sysv.shmmax: 33554432` and `kern.sysv.shmseg: 64` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove Postgres which I install via Brew, and then I reinstalled Postgres.app, and then restarted my computer, and then opening the app and clicking 'initialize' fixed it.